# Intent that opens "new calendar event" activity

Tags: android, calendar, android-intent

In my app, I want a functionality to create calendar event. I open "new calendar event" activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");
intent.putExtra("description", "Some description");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", eventStartInMillis);
intent.putExtra("endTime", eventEndInMillis);
startActivity(intent);
```

It works perfectly on stock Android. On HTC Sense, I have only one issue - end time is not set correctly, it's always one hour after begin time. What can be the problem?

Comment: The calendar is not part of the Android SDK. Your code may not work in future versions of Android (e.g., Android 2.2). Your code may not work on various devices where they have replaced the calendar. Please do not attempt to manipulate the calendar.

Comment: I know that, but it's better if it's working for the majority of devices than if I remove this functionality for all devices. My app is useful in the Czech Republic, where all available devices have stock Android (add to calendar 100% working) or HTC Sense (where add to calendar feature has only minor issue).

Comment: @CommonsWare what the customers want they get ;) but good to know that this isn't easy on Android. Had hopped there were some kind of global intent all calendar apps could hook in on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had a bug in my code - the value of eventEndInMillis was wrong and it was smaller then eventStartInMillis.