# Add to Calendar on HTC One not handling event end value

Tags: android, android-calendar

In an Android app, I'm trying to add an event to the native calendar. This code works fine on multiple other devices (4.4.2, or 5.0.2, Nexus 7, Nexus 9, other phones), but fails on the HTC One, which insists that I'm passing it a one hour event.

Debug shows that the data is getting passed correctly, and all the devices tested report these same values for the same event, even the HTC One.

```
04-01 14:13:32.545 ...﹕ sendAddToCalendarIntent
04-01 14:13:32.545 ...﹕ title: Spring Break
04-01 14:13:32.545 ...﹕ start: 1427811600000
04-01 14:13:32.545 ...﹕ end  : 1428099600000
```

Code for launching the Intent below:

```
// Creating intent for native Calendar App
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(Events.TITLE, title)
        .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, content)
        .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
if (endTime == -1) {
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);
} else {
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there something 'unique' about the HTC One in this regard? (even a known defect I haven't found out on the web yet would let me put this to rest)

Answer (score 0):

yes i think it is a 'bug' for HTC. I've spent a lot of time researching and trying to fix this  "one hour ahead only" issue since I first came across it a couple years ago. I think there are other devices that do not work perfectly or in a standard way for the **device Calendar** but from the ones I have been able to test, HTC devices are the only ones I can't find a work-around to enter in all event details correctly.

[Intent that opens "new calendar event" activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911731/intent-that-opens-new-calendar-event-activity) this is the only other question I've seen address this specific problem but like you, I know that there is nothing wrong with the data being passed in.